# Writing database library in Scala - initialization code

Tags: scala, library-design

I wanted to write small library for `Neo4j` database in Scala language. This library will talk with `Neo4j` database and mostly map classes to nodes. I want to make it work like `spray-json` library: https://github.com/spray/spray-json

Anyway I was wondering about one thing, what is the best way to implement initialization code in library?

For example in `Spring Data Neo4j` when you create application context with `Neo4j` beans, the line `val ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(...)` invokes some code that creates indexes in `Neo4j` based on annotations.

Should steps like that be achieved through using static methods in constructor/factory methods (in `Scala` it would probably be some companion object)? And if so, how would I proceed if I want no explicit invocation of initialization code, meaning the first time I use something from my library initialization happens but it is cached somewhere - I was thinking of using lazy vals to store required information for my library in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should steps like that be achieved through using static methods in
>   constructor/factory methods (in Scala it would probably be some
>   companion object)?

No, the word *initialization* implies state and having global state is antipattern. I really like how [casbah](https://mongodb.github.io/casbah/tutorial.html) was designed:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
val mongoClient = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)

val database = mongoClient("test")
// now the actual work with databases and encompassed collections 
db.collectionNames
val coll = db("test")
...
```

So now, I can have multiple instances of clients, which is really useful not only for the main app code, but **for the testing**. Moreover, having everything in object, as you proposed above, may complicate things in case of **multi-threaded** application.

> And if so, how would I proceed if I want no explicit invocation of
>   initialization code, meaning the first time I use something from my
>   library initialization happens but it is cached somewhere - I was
>   thinking of using lazy vals to store required information for my
>   library in this case.

Why don't you roll out session-like (i.e. `MongoClient` in code above) object and cache everything inside it?

FYI, [loan pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762240/loan-pattern-in-scala), it do not relate directly with your inquiry, but it's a good option when you implement scala APIs

Comment: Thanks for answer, you are probably right with the per-session caching and avoiding global state, I will take a look at the `Casbah` source code for some inspiration.

Comment: Note, that Casbah is deemed to be v1 mongo api for scala, there is also new-wave [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/), which is aimed on async operations, though I can't say much about it, since I had no working experience with it.