# how to test my pyspark streaming without spark and kafka environment

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I wrote my python code local,it is about spark streaming pulling data from kafka and do some rdd operation,I would like to test if my rdd operation satisfied my expection,but I have not set up kafka and spark,how to test my job?

Comment: maybe something like unit test?anybody knows?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507988/how-to-test-spark-rdd